# Should I get results in real time while my webserver is running if I haven't done any html for a google app engine web app?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-applications, frameworks, runtime

when I run it against localhost it shouldn't show anything if I haven't made any html right? Or is it because of some kind of database issue? I checked the page source and there is nothing like it should be, but I'm not entirely certain about specification of get requests and how they work in this case.

Despite the fact that i has response.write, etc.? I'm thinking that it shouldn't show anything in localhost because its a web app now utilizing the web app framework right? By the way I auto-generated the beginning part of the project using the pycharm ide.

I realize this may be a dumb question, but I'm a newb. 
This is my main.py file:

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
    self.response.out.write('Hello, webapp World!')

application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                 [('/', MainPage)],
                                 debug=True)

def main():
run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Here is my app.yaml file:

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
script: helloworld.py
```

Comment: Including some code might help people help you. Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: It's not a database problem.  Your code looks okay except for a bad indent in main() which is probably a cut/paste into SO.  (Visual inspection only, I didn't run it.)  Is your Python code in main.py?  Because your app.yaml says helloworld.py. Check the logs when running on localhost.  Another experiment to try: comment out the Content-Type header for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The intent of the code is to show `'Hello, webapp World!'` then you request `/` url on the server. So if the code doesn't contain any errors then you should get results both on localhost and on appengine (if you deploy it).